# Backup database by copy mdf and ldf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want backup and restore my database in C# application that database create with Visual Studio.

I want backup my database by copying the `.mdf` and `.ldf` file into one place and for restore back them to their place.

How can I do that?

I want do that with C# like 
System.IO.File.Copy(Application.StartupPath + "\DBSP.mdf", Application.StartupPath + "\DBSP.mdf", true);

But it says this is using by another process

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/restore-sql-server-backup-file-with-C-Sharp/ use this for solved your problem

Comment: One word: **DON'T!** Use the proper SQL Server `BACKUP DATABASE` and `RESTORE DATABASE`  commands instead

Comment: First, stop the SQL Server service of your instance, then you can copy and restore this files. Be careful not to mix a .mdf with a .ldf older a newer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server management studio, right click on Databases then select Attach.
Then provide the MDF file location to attached the copied database to the intended server.